# LSD.test from agricolae package: group output question

Tags: r

I have a general question about the LSD.test() function. It says in the documentation that in the output for groups that groups with the same letter are not statistically different from each other. However, I've seen a few cases where it will output two letters for a group (i.e. AB or something similar) and I haven't been able to figure out exactly what that means. This page (https://rdrr.io/cran/agricolae/man/LSD.test.html) suggests that there is overlap with another one of the groups, which I would assume means that it's not statistically different?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying method for generating group letters is `agricolae::orderPvalue` which orders *p*-values according to the group means, and then assigns letters based on *p*-values and a pre-defined statistical significance level `alpha`.

Let's take a look at the example that is given in `?orderPvalue`:

[image]

Here

1. B is statistically significantly different from A, and B has the largest mean therefore gets group letter "a",
2. conversely, A is statistically significantly different from B, and A has the second largest mean (of groups that are statistically significantly different) therefore has group letter "b",
3. C is *not* statistically significantly different from A nor B, therefore shares a letter with that from group A and B giving it "ab"

Comment: Thank you! I had assumed this was the case but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: You're very welcome @Justin. Since you're new to SO, please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for others to find relevant posts. It also grants a small rep reward to the original poster and answerer, which is the [SO-recommended way to say "thank you"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).